# matching property in agenda view

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want collect and create a block containing headlines which only has "ID" property in the headlines.

i.e The headlines to be filtered looks like

```
* Headline 
   :PROPERTIES:
   :ID: my-id
   :END:
```

I am using the following code to configure the custom agenda command which does not work

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
           '(("c" "MY Agenda"
          ((tags "ID")))))
```

I have read the org manual http://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties but still unable to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code as such is asking it to find all headlines that have a `:ID:` tag on the headline.  To look for properties you have to use the property match feature which is listed a bit lower on the linked manual page.

Since I'm assuming you need it to match any ID and not just a specific ID you'll have to use the regexp matching by either matching (`=`) or not matching (`<>`) the regexp that follows in curly brackets.

To match your ID property you'll need the regexp to be `ID={.+}`.  If you used `.*` as the match it would also match headlines without any ID property.  If you have some a set of IDs you want to match that have something in common you can adjust the regexp to match them.

So your custom agenda command will have to be:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
           '(("c" "MY Agenda"
          ((tags "ID={.+}")))))
```