# filtering headlines which does not contain a particular PROPERTY

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to set up the custom command using

```
org-agenda-custom-commands
```

variable, which should select the headlines which does not contain the PROPERTY named "ID". 
What is the filter expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the reverse match of looking for headlines that match `ID`.  From the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties)

> A search string can use Boolean operators ‘&’ for AND and ‘|’ for OR.
>   ‘&’ binds more strongly than ‘|’. Parentheses are currently not
>   implemented. Each element in the search is either a tag, a regular
>   expression matching tags, or an expression like PROPERTY OPERATOR
>   VALUE with a comparison operator, accessing a property value. Each
>   element may be preceded by ‘-’, to select against it, and ‘+’ is
>   syntactic sugar for positive selection. The AND operator ‘&’ is
>   optional when ‘+’ or ‘-’ is present. Here are some examples, using
>   only tags.

Using the same query as in your question [Matching property in agenda view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033797/matching-property-in-agenda-view), you simply negate the search and it will provide all lines that do not match on ID.

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
           '(("c" "MY Agenda"
          ((tags "-ID={.+}")))))
```

Comment: Is it possible to use such filtering while using `agenda` instead of `tags` as 3rd argument (that is, start with a n-days agenda view, and pile filters over that) ? (I can post this as a whole question, maybe.)